# How to enable monitoring in Oracle Service Bus 11g?

Tags: oracle, osb

I have been looking to enable monitoring in OSB 11g? I am not exactly sure how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "monitoring" as there are many different kinds and a lot depends on your functional requirements around monitoring too. 
Monitoring can be:
*** Proactive** *(When you actively look for patterns - preferably automatically but also possible manually - and detect issues before they occur or get alerted to those immediately after they occur)*
*** Reactive** *(when you are trying to debug an issue after it has occurred)*

Monitoring can also be:
*** Technical** - check for signs of timeouts, long running invocations etc. Technical monitoring can be at:

- Application level *(OSB specific in your case)*
- Platform level *(Application server/JVM/operating system - after all, for OSB monitoring to work, you need to ensure/monitor that the OSB itself is running!)*

***Functional** (often involves explicit logging from your code but can be co-related to technical patterns - e.g. number of invocations of a particular API/service might indicate number of orders).

- Functional monitoring can also include SLA monitoring

**Finally, in the Oracle Service bus**:
* You can enable monitoring at the individual service level *(via the Operations tab under each service or via scripting in WSLT)* 
* The monitoring above can be combined with rules to alert on specifc scenarios (such as SLA breaches) 
* You can use specific log entries within your pipelines and then monitor those at runtime

There is a lot more you can do to "monitor" services depending on what is relevant for your services. Although OSB monitoring can be performed via various consoles (/sbconsole or /em in 12c), a lot of good monitoring combines these features into well designed **alerts** so that you are always on top of potential problems. You can reach this stage by constantly observing your system's behaviour and then improving/tweaking your monitoring solution(s). 

This is a good document to read to start:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/admin.1111/e15867/monitoring_ops.htm#OSBAG472

HTH.

Comment: Thank you Jang, as I said in my question I am just staring this and your post deemed to be very useful.